# I need to migrate from my Shopify to Magento?

Tags: migration

I have been used Shopify for my store in 1 year and now i need to migrate all data from Shopify to Magento (including customers password). What should i do? Pls advice me. Thx

Comment: why should you care about passwords ?? the biggest problem is your products and customers details, as orders and some shopping history.

Comment: Such a common thing I hear from store owners, they don't want to "inconvenience" users by forcing them to set new passwords. In reality, telling users they need to reset their password shows that you don't brush off security measures as unimportant.

Answer (score 3):

There are some big issues with access to all the data in Shopify, especially surrounding gift cards.  You can try services like Cart2Cart  http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Migrate-All-Data-from-Shopify-to-Magento-in/

Or you can get a Partner to migrate you.  I've worked with Gauge Interactive (www.gaugeinteractive.com) and they have done a few migrations from Shopify to Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't mind using a paid service, I suggest you go ahead and read [this article](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Migrate-All-Data-from-Shopify-to-Magento-in/) otherwise you'll have to code it by hand, but it could be difficult. You could also take a look [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/litextension-shopify-to-magento-migration-tool.html) but I don't know this extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would be amazed if you can take customer passwords - in order to be able to store them you would need to be able to decode them and to do that you would need to know how they were first encrypted which should be very well guarded secret on Shopify's part?

Do a full export from Shopify and then you would have to convert or parse the resulting CSV into one compatible with Magento. If your database of products is large - I would suggest you look at creating the products with a script - there are plenty of articles out there on the subject then you can run it at your own pace.

Import your Shopify CSV into a temporary table then parse each product 1 at a time?